# Let's have a chat!

Tags: discussion, chat

[Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/aviation) is a little bit lonely at the moment! `:(`

> [image]

Leave a message and let's get the chat rolling!

---

You can access it by clicking the SE logo in the top bar and clicking chat:

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that Chat is buried in the Stack Exchange menu probably doesn't help with making it a lively place :)

Comment: Could't possibly agree more, wish they would change that, maybe make it easier to bookmark it too...